# Write a c++ program that outputs the longest win streak after the user inputs 10 results

Tags: algorithm

This was a question given to us on a practice test and I've been trying to solve it but haven't really made any progress. I am supposed to write a program that will read 10 characters, each being a w or l, for win or loss. The program is supposed to compute the longest win streak. For example:
"l l w w l w w w w l" will give an output of 4. "l w l w l w l w l w" will give an output of 1. I've been messing around with this question but am not sure where to go. Also note, we haven't covered anything more than your basic if/else, while/do while, for loops, switch statements. This is not an assignment for points, just simply a problem on a practice test.

Comment: How would you solve this without a computer?

Comment: The first time I saw a w, I would add 1 to my win streak. If the next input was also a w, add 1 more. But if I am given a 'l' and my streak ends and later down the line I start another streak, I'm not sure how to differentiate between the two streaks without adding them together.

Comment: you can use some simple dynamic programming

Comment: @ssovukluk some rad overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem could be easily solved in O(n) time complexity.

So you just need to keep two variables, one is called max_cnt and another one is cur_cnt. So as you iterate over the string, increment the cur_cnt if you find a 'w' else make cur_cnt = 0. Now at the end of each iterations just check the value of cur_cnt with max_cnt and if cur_cnt > max_cnt, then you set max_cnt = cur_cnt.

Have a look at my implementation for this problem. The code is written in c++.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string s = "llwwlwwwwl";
  int max_cnt = 0;
  int cur_cnt = 0;
  for(int i=0; i<s.length(); i++) {
    if(s[i]=='l') {
      cur_cnt = 0;
    } else {
      cur_cnt++;
    }
    max_cnt = max(max_cnt, cur_cnt);
  }
  cout<<max_cnt<<endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if I have made any mistake or more explanation is required on my approach.

Comment: Thanks! So, this helps, I understand what is happening looking at your code. I still believe there are some differences based on what the problem said, which could be my fault. So, "s.length()" I'm assuming is simply the length of the string. We haven't covered that yet. Also, the user is supposed to manually input the individual wins and losses. I am having a bit of trouble on how I should go about getting the user to input the values, storing them, and iterating through them. I feel like the rest of the logic in your code still applies though!

Comment: Actually, I think I just figured it out!

Comment: happy to help @JimmyBlundell